# Cocoapods/ CrittercismSDK causing App Submission Error: ITMS-90035

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crittercism

I am trying to upload an app to Testflight using XCode 6.3. However, on trying to validate the app, it is giving me the error message below:

I have tried regenerating the certificates and provisioning profiles without having any success.

> ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. Code object is not signed
>   at all. The binary at path [VirtualMechanic.app/dsym_upload.sh]
>   contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your
>   application with a distribution certificate, not an ad hoc certificate
>   or a development certificate. Verify that the code signing settings in
>   Xcode are correct at the target level (which override any values at
>   the project level). Additionally, make sure the bundle you are
>   uploading was built using a Release target in Xcode, not a Simulator
>   target. If you are certain your code signing settings are correct,
>   choose "Clean All" in Xcode, delete the "build" directory in the
>   Finder, and rebuild your release target. For more information, please
>   consult
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That `dsym_upload.sh` script does not belong in the app bundle as it's the script that is run as part of a *Build Phase* that is used to upload the debug symbols to Crittercism.

Find the *Build Phase* that is copying it into the app bundle and remove it, however please note that it will still need to be run within a *Build Phase*.

Here's the official [Crittercism Support Article](http://support.crittercism.com/articles/knowledge_base/iOS-App-rejection-issue-for-the-Apps-built-using-CocoaPods) related to the issue which recommends upgrading the pod to version 5.2.0.

Comment: I cannot find the file within Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources. But I do have a Run Script that looks like this: 

`APP_ID="XYZ"
API_KEY="XYZ"
source "${SRCROOT}"/Pods/CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh`

Comment: @AshishAgarwal That is the Build Phase that needs to remain.  If you cannot find the offending *Copy Files*, then you will need to start digging deeper into the scripts that are run.  It's there somewhere.

Comment: I have this line in one of the files in the Pods project: 
`install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh"` What does it do ?

Comment: Yeah that's the line.  Remove it.  Clean. Archive. Submit.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal Please note I have editted my answer to provide the official Crittercism support article related to this.